# Why cannot libspotify save to cache?

Tags: c#, .net, libspotify

Running my C# application from Visual studio works fine (in this respect)

But when installing the application in my system (win7, .NET 4.0) I get problems with the cache.

These are the errors I get:

> LogMessageCallback. Message:20:43:03.988 E [playlist:1978] Unable to save file: playlist.bnk
>
> LogMessageCallback. Message:20:43:03.988 E [social-mgr:830] Unable to save file: social_stream.bnk
>
> LogMessageCallback. Message:20:46:31.034 E [user_cache:107] Unable to save file: user-cache.bnk
>
> LogMessageCallback. Message:20:43:04.988 I [c:/Users/spotify-buildagent/BuildAgent/work/1e0ce8a77adfb2dc/client/core/protocol/file_streamer_simple.cpp:769] Request for file 57a6ab34bad26645e2345a610ae652fe77f82afb complete (code: 0)

I have tried to deleted the entire cache library and it gets recreated when I start the app, so it can't be a matter of file privilege.

Since the cache does not seem to be valid my playlists are not accessible to me at startup.

I do log out properly.

Any explanation/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it...

I search for the playlist.bnk file on my disk and found one under Spotify\bin\Debug\cache_location\Users\bes51659-user, that is from where I run my project with visual studio. "cache_location" in the path directed me to the settings_location argument in the config struct when creating the session. I had set it to const string "cache_location". I must have understood the explanation wrong:

https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/structsp__session__config.html#a342532432040d476aaaf73f10893d23b

> The location where Spotify will write setting files and per-user cache items. This includes playlists, track metadata, etc. 'settings_location' may be the same path as 'cache_location'. 'settings_location' folder will not be created (unlike 'cache_location'), if you don't want to create the folder yourself, you can set 'settings_location' to 'cache_location'.

(a bit contradictory that the "cache_location" catalog was actually created under debug!)

The comment must mean that if I reuse the same location for setting_location as for cache_location I do not have to create it as it has already been created!

I do not know if libspotify did not have permissions to create the catalog "cache_location" under "program files", or if it expected it to be there and did not find it. But it does not matter. I have now changed both the locations to "c:\mySpotify" in the config struct and problem solved...

My only excuse is that google tells me that I'm not the first to have fallen into this pithole.